# Multi core batch volume gain

Tags: sound, process, batch

I need to process a large number of mp3 files in order to boost volume.

I am currently using MP3Gain which is fine but slow.

I need any software that does the same but take advantage of the multi core capabilities of my processors so I could process various files at the same time.

Looking for something in Windows, though Linux would also work.

Answer (score 2):

What OS?

A quick Google of MP3Gain tells me it hasn't been updated in 5 years, there's likely to be a better solution…

iTunes, for instance, can gain-balance to some extent. As MP3Gain claims to not re-encode, then it's not doing any compression, merely tagging playback volume in the same way iTunes does.

Answer (score 1):

If it's *a large number of files*, then going parallel is very easy and can be done with *any* tool (though it won't always be efficient): just let the OS run multiple processes independently!

For instance, with [the simple standard GNU tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel),

```
find ./ -name '*mp3' | parallel mp3gain -g 2 
                               # not really a useful mp3gain command, dunno how you use it...
```

which will work only when you can actually process each file on its own.

If you need to process entire albums (directories) as-one, you have to change it to

```
 find ./ -type d | parallel -X "find {} -name '*.mp3' | xargs mp3gain -g 2"
```

and so on, depending on what exactly you want to achieve.